# SSL POST fails from CURL Command Line Script but succeeds from PHP Script

Tags: php, curl, rackspace-cloud

I'm attempting to perform an authentication on Rackspace Cloud Services. Basically this involves POSTing a JSON string to https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens and then receiving a JSON result in the response.

However, I'm having issues with this i.e. It works in PHP but it doesn't work when I use CURL from the command line.

When I do this in the command line:

```
curl -s https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens -X POST -d '{"auth":{"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{"username":"<my_username>", "apiKey":"<my_apikey>"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

It doesn't not work i.e. I receive `{"badRequest":{"code":400,"message":"JSON Parsing error"}}` as the response. I should point out that `<my_username>` and `<my_apikey>` are my username and api key as per Rackpace Cloud Credentials.

But when I do the following in PHP Code:

```
$post_data = '{"auth":{"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials":{"username":"<my_username>", "apiKey":"<my_apikey>"}}}';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($post_data))
);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

It works and I get the JSON data like I'm supposed to.

I would like to know why PHP is working but CURL on Command Line is not?! Thanks!

P.S. I'm using a Windows 7 PC.

**EDIT**

It also works when I take the JSON string and put it in a file and then do this:

```
curl -s https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens -X POST -d @myfile.json -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just decided to try something I had refused to believe would need to be done to resolve my problem, and it turns out that it was the solution.

The following works:

```
curl -s https://identity.api.rackspacecloud.com/v2.0/tokens -X POST -d "{\"auth\":{\"RAX-KSKEY:apiKeyCredentials\":{\"username\":\"<my_username>\", \"apiKey\":\"<my_apikey>\"}}}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Subtle difference i.e. I used double-quotes to encapsulate the JSON string (instead of single quotes) and then escaped the double-quotes inside the JSON string.

This might be a Windows-only issue!

Comment: Great to hear! It was working on my Mac with your exact example, so I'm glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks. I contacted Rackspace Support earlier and the person I was on with was using a Mac and couldn't replicate the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: go through all the options you set in the php script and find the corresponding command line options (e.g. via the `man` page). Then try the command again.

Comment: Looked into that and can't figure out what else to add. I looks like it has something to do with the way CURL is parsing the JSON string.